# Rounding and Formatting in SAS

Tags: formatting, sas

I am converting numeric variables (p-values) to character variables by way of the put function.  I would like to retain the pvaluew.d format's usage of '<.0001' for values of less than .0001.  I am using the code below:

```
newvar=put(round(oldvar,.0001),pvalue6.4);
```

I ran into an issue with this.  The newvar ended up being either 1 or <.0001 when I used this.
I wasnt able to reproduce this error when I tried it on other parts of my code, leading me to believe that something else I did was the problem.

Using an example, I used the above transformation and the one below on a variable with some random p-values in it:

```
newvar2=put(oldvar,pvalue6.4);
```

The results are identical.  Should this always be the case, that the two strings of code will produce identical resutls, and my previous error was due to another cause, or could there be instances of differing results?  I could just use a `6.4` format for the put function and change any 0.0000 to <.0001 manually, but prefer to let SAS do it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most formats automatically round when displaying, so you shouldn't need to do the rounding.

```
data _null_;
 do x=.00004,.00006,.00014,.00016;
   y=round(x,.0001);
   put x= pvalue6.4 y= pvalue6.4;
 end;
run;
```

The only difference between the two processes is that the `pvalue` format will display numbers from .0005 - .000999 as '<.0001' while rounding first will display those numbers as equal to .0001.  Which is correct for your project is your choice; I suspect most would prefer the former, unless you felt that .0001 was the furthest significant digit you can correctly display.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Has SAS always rounded automatically in a put function to d signinficant digits, or was this functionality added?

Comment: Rounding varies by the format, but it's always (in v9 at least) done so as far as I know in numeric formats.  Picture formats default to NOT rounding, but most of the built-in picture formats (such as `pvalue`) do round.

Comment: I found something interesting.  If I use a put function (with a normal w.d format) without a round function on a negative number and it gets rounded to zero, then the negative seems to still be displayed, -0.0000 for example.